# Compress to tar.gz on Grunt

Tags: shell, gzip, tar, gruntjs

This is driving me crazy, I'm just trying to compress a folder like:

```
tar -czvf app.tar.gz ./app/
```

an obviously it works just fine, but https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-shell produces a corrupted tar.gz:

```
shell: {
  deploy: {
    command: 'tar -czvf app.tar.gz ./app/'
  }
}
```

I've tried https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-compress without luck (and I prefer to use the shell one because after the compression I'll do another thing with the tar.gz).

My stack:

OSX                    10.8.3
node                   0.10.4
Grunt                  0.4.1
grunt-shell            0.2.2
grunt-contrib-compress 0.5.0

**Thanks to @hereandnow78 for point out the sequence thing!**

If you have:

```
shell: {
  deploy: {
    command: 'tar -cfvz app.tar.gz ./app/'
  }
},
```

Then it'll give you a tar.gz file called "vz" (without extension) with the right content.

But, if you have:

```
shell: {
  deploy: {
    command: 'tar -czf app.tar.gz ./app/'
  }
},
```

Then it works as expected... So the issue comes from the verbose param, maybe it has something to do with using stdout for the verbose info?

What is really annoying is that `tar -czvf app.tar.gz ./app/` works just fine outside the grunt task.

**Would someone please clarify this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the sequence of your tar options should be important

try it in this sequence:

```
-cfvz
```

which means:

```
- c: create
- f: a file
- v: verbose
- z: additionally compress with gzip
```